# .9.png that de-compiled from apk causes error

Tags: android

I de-compiled or unzip a apk file and gain its `.9.png` image. When I use this `.9.png` image in my project, it causes error, showing bad patches.

I also see some discussion about this on google code. I would like to know it it is possible to use the `.9.png` image from unziped or de-compild apk in my own project.

Comment: sounds like you're stealing other images from APK not owned by you.

Comment: well,not stealing, just learning.

Comment: This error came due to bad patches in your 9 patch image so try to learn from here : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: `de-compiled from apk` or **just unzipped**? it's really a different thing. Unzipping from the apk won't give you the **real** 9 patches.